# Does tomcat7 supports for SAML 2.0?

Tags: apache, tomcat7, saml, saml-2.0

My application is running on Apache 2.0 server and my java code is deployed on Tomcat 7.0. Now i am going to introduce Single sign-on concept into my application.

Does tomcat 7.0 support SAML 2.0? 
If yes please clarify , compatibility-wise what is the difference between SAML 1.0 and SAML 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7.0 does not look to have **native** SAML support but since you don't specify particular restricions and want to introduce Single Sign On you might be interested in Apache CXF Suite ([link to SSO page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/saml-web-sso.html)), in particular Fediz plugin (see [architecture](http://cxf.apache.org/fediz-architecture.html) ).

SAML 1.x to SAML 2.x main concerns (as protocols) are that 2.x is not backwards-compatible (new and renamed XML tags, protocol and binding changes).
If you ask which version is "better" to choose fresh, I say 2.x if you need to support both you might need a kind of converting gateway/proxy (Fediz supports 1.1 tokens but I didn't use it)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge Tomcat 7 does not have a SAML SP provider implementation. You may have a look at  SAML Spring Security extension o picket link (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/PLINK/Service+Provider+Configuration)